# RegExp is not working for '$' sign

Tags: regex

Below is my code in regexp. here I want to match a "t" variable to the $var_string. If t=$ then it is not working.

```
<script>
$regex = new RegExp(t , 'g' );
$res = $var_string.match($regex);
$var_string_length = $var_string.length;
if($res.length >= 2 ){                                      
$var_string = $var_string.substring(0, $var_string_length - 1);                       
$("#my_popup4").popup('show');
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a reserved character in regex.  It is used to match the end of a given string. This site explains it in detail. [Link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

You'll need to escape it:

```
<script>
var t = "\$";
$regex = new RegExp(t , 'g' );
$res = $var_string.match($regex);
$var_string_length = $var_string.length;
if($res.length >= 2 ){                                      
$var_string = $var_string.substring(0, $var_string_length - 1);                       
$("#my_popup4").popup('show');
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Here t is the dynamic variable. which I match next in $var_string string.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to match a string with a dollar sign in it you'll need to escape it. Otherwise it will be interpreted as part of the regular expression.

Comment: what to do if I have to match $ in a string, using regexp.?

Comment: Try a string replaxe. `t = t.replace("$","\\$")`.

Comment: nope..it didn't work.

Comment: http://mastersoftwaretechnologies.com/slot-game/

Comment: Can you provide a full input string example?

Comment: As in above app, you can see that not every alphabet can written twice as $.